# What to choose Spring ROO or Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-roo

What is the better of the two. Spring ROO or GRAILS ? What variables can be used to choose between the two to implement the project in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a personal perspective it boiled down to Spring Roo making use of AspectJ, but otherwise being Java under the covers.  So we went with Spring Roo because it didn't lock us in to anything (other then the Spring framework) and was easy to push in/out of the classes.